# Groovy compare two collections except first item

Tags: java, groovy, collections

I have two collections and I need to compare those list and verify all the items are equal except the first item.

below is my collections

```
def mapA = [a: 'test', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']
def mapB = [a: 'test0', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']
```

in my case first item always differ, so how should I verify the above collections except for first item [a]

Comment: Maps are not sorted/ordered by default.  The groovy map literal gives you an ordered one - but depending on your source of those maps, "first" might be a trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

### Comparing key sets

One way is to extract key sets from both maps, remove the key that you are not interested in, check if both sets are the same and then compare if all values from both maps for given keys are equal.

```
def mapA = [a: 'test', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']
def mapB = [a: 'test0', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']

def keysA = mapA.keySet() - 'a'
def keysB = mapB.keySet() - 'a'

assert keysA == keysB && keysA.every { key -> mapA[key] == mapB[key] }
```

### Comparing intersections equality

You can also create an intersection of two maps and check if the intersection has expected size and if it does not contain a key that you know that holds a different value.

```
def mapA = [a: 'test', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']
def mapB = [a: 'test0', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']

def intersection = mapA.intersect(mapB)

assert intersection.size() == mapA.size() - 1 && !intersection.containsKey('a')
```

### Removing `a` key and comparing maps

Another way to achieve it is to remove the key you know contains a value that is different in both maps and then check equality. Keep in mind that `Map.remove(object)` mutates the input map, so you might need to create a copy of the object first.

```
def mapA = [a: 'test', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']
def mapB = [a: 'test0', b: 'test1', c: 'test2']

mapA.remove('a')
mapB.remove('a')

assert mapA == mapB
```